# How to determine cause of "RuntimeError: Resource temporarily unavailable" error in Python notebook

Tags: python, python-c-api, duckdb

In a hosted Python notebook, I'm using the [`duckdb` library](https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb) and running this code:

```
duckdb.connect(database=":memory:", read_only=False)
```

This returns the following error sometimes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-70-fbc34423bc92>", line 5, in <cell line: 4>
    duckdb.connect(database=":memory:", read_only=False)
RuntimeError: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I'm not sure how to see where DuckDB's native code is failing. What can be done to determine what resource is unavailable and thus the cause of the error? In my environment, I can run arbitrary Python as well as shell commands via the notebook using `!shell-cmd` syntax.